# Send array from custom cell to another view controller

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

i'm running a query to Firebase and the results are displaying in a custom cell. The cell has a UIButton that when tapped it goes to another view controller where the user can enter info. The question i have is, how do i send the array in the custom cell to the next view controller? i need to send the array so i can reference the subcollection of info i'm going to add for each array. Segue is working properly,  when i print to the console, the array is empty "nil". Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Custom Cell**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

protocol PatCellCommentsDelegate {
func patCommentBtnTapped (ptcomments: [Comment])
}

class PatdataCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var ptnameLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dobLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var finLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var officemdLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var assignedmdLbl: UILabel?
@IBOutlet weak var appnameLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var assigneddateLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var roomnumberLbl: UILabel?
@IBOutlet weak var diagnosesLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var reasonforadmitorconsultLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var goalofhospitalizationLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var seenoseeLbl: UILabel?
@IBOutlet weak var notestocboLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var numCommentsLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var hospitalLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var teamLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var addCommentBtn: UIButton!

var ptdata: PTData!
var ptcomments = [Comment]()
var delegate: PatCellCommentsDelegate?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

func configurePatDataCell(ptdata: PTData, delegate: 
PatCellCommentsDelegate) {

    self.ptdata = ptdata
    self.delegate = delegate
    ptnameLbl.text = ptdata.ptname
    dobLbl.text = ptdata.dob
    finLbl.text = ptdata.fin
    officemdLbl.text = ptdata.officemd
    assignedmdLbl?.text = ptdata.assignedmd
    appnameLbl.text = ptdata.app
    assigneddateLbl.text = ptdata.assigneddate
    roomnumberLbl?.text = ptdata.room
    diagnosesLbl.text = ptdata.diagnoses
    reasonforadmitorconsultLbl.text = ptdata.reasonforadmitorconsult
    goalofhospitalizationLbl.text = ptdata.goalofhospitalization
    seenoseeLbl?.text = ptdata.seenosee
    notestocboLbl.text = ptdata.notestocbo
    numCommentsLbl.text = ptdata.comments
    hospitalLbl.text = ptdata.hosp
    teamLbl.text = ptdata.team

    }

  @IBAction func addCommentBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

   //trying to send data to commentsVC from this cell

   delegate?.patCommentBtnTapped(ptcomments: self.ptcomments)
  }
  }
```

**View Controller**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import SVProgressHUD

class PatdataVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource, PatCellCommentsDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var patDataTableView: UITableView!

var ptdatas = [PTData]()
var ptComments = [Comment]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    patDataTableView.delegate = self
    patDataTableView.dataSource = self
    patDataTableView.rowHeight = 1150

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToComments" {
        let commtsVC = segue.destination as! CommentsVC
        commtsVC.ptComments = ptComments
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            }
        }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
section: Int) -> Int {
        return ptdatas.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == patDataTableView {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
"PatdataCell", for: indexPath) as? PatdataCell
        cell!.configurePatDataCell(ptdata: ptdatas[indexPath.row], 
delegate: self)
        return cell!
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}

func patCommentBtnTapped (ptcomments: [Comment]) {

    self.ptComments = ptcomments
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToComments", sender: self)
}

}
```

**CommentsVC**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore 

class CommentsVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource, CommentsDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var commentTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var addCommentTxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var keyboardView: UIView!

var ptComments = [Comment]()
var commentsPtData: Comment!
var commentRef: DocumentReference!
var username: String!
var commentListener : ListenerRegistration!
let firestore = Firestore.firestore()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    commentTableView.dataSource = self
    commentTableView.delegate = self
    commentTableView.rowHeight = 110

    //commentRef = 
firestore.collection(PTLIST_REF).document(commentsPtData.documentId)
    //        if let name = Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName{
    //            username = name
    //    }

    self.view.bindToKeyboard()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    commentListener = 

firestore.collection(PTLIST_REF).document(self.commentsPtData
.documentId)
        .collection(COMMENTS_REF)
        .order(by: TIMESTAMP, descending: false)
        .addSnapshotListener({ (snapshot, error) in
            guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
                debugPrint("Error Fetching comments: \(Error.self)")
                return
            }

            self.ptComments.removeAll()
            self.ptComments = Comment.parseData(snapshot: snapshot)
            self.commentTableView.reloadData()
        })
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    commentListener.remove()
}

func commentOptionsTapped(commentsCellPtData: Comment) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Edit Comment", message: "You 
can delete or edit", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete Comment", style: 
.default) { (action) in

        self.firestore.runTransaction({ (transaction, errorPointer) -> 
Any? in

            let ptListDocument: DocumentSnapshot

            do {
                try ptListDocument = 

 transaction.getDocument(Firestore.firestore()
.collection(PTLIST_REF).document(self.commentsPtData.documentId))
            } catch let error as NSError {
                debugPrint("Fetch Error: \ . 
(error.localizedDescription)")
                return nil
            }

            guard let oldNumComments = ptListDocument.data()! 
 [NUM_COMMENTS] as? Int else { return nil }

            transaction.updateData([NUM_COMMENTS : oldNumComments - 
 1], forDocument: self.commentRef!)

            let commentRef =  
 self.firestore.collection(PTLIST_REF).document(self
 .commentsPtData.documentId).collection(COMMENTS_REF)
 .document(commentsCellPtData.documentId!)

            transaction.deleteDocument(commentRef)

            return nil
        }) { (object, error) in
            if let error = error {
                debugPrint("transaction failed: \(error)")
            } else {
                alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    let editAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Edit Comment", style: 
.default) { (action) in

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toEditComment", sender: 
(commentsCellPtData, self.commentsPtData))
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, 
handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(deleteAction)
    alert.addAction(editAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

@IBAction func addCommentTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let commentTxt = addCommentTxt.text else { return }

    firestore.runTransaction({ (transaction, errorPointer) -> Any? in

        let ptListDocument: DocumentSnapshot

        do {
            try ptListDocument = 
transaction.getDocument(Firestore.firestore()
.collection(PTLIST_REF).document(self.commentsPtData.documentId))
        } catch let error as NSError {
            debugPrint("Fetch Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return nil
        }

        guard let oldNumComments = ptListDocument.data()! 
[NUM_COMMENTS] as? Int else { return nil }

        transaction.updateData([NUM_COMMENTS : oldNumComments + 1], 
forDocument: self.commentRef!)

        let newCommentRef = 
self.firestore.collection(PTLIST_REF).document((self
.commentsPtData.documentId)).collection(COMMENTS_REF).document()

        transaction.setData([
            COMMENT_TXT : commentTxt,
            TIMESTAMP : FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            USERNAME : self.username!,
            USER_ID : Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? ""
            ], forDocument: newCommentRef)

        return nil
    }) { (object, error) in
        if let error = error {
            debugPrint("transaction failed: \(error)")
        } else {
            self.addCommentTxt.text = ""
            self.addCommentTxt.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
section: Int) -> Int {
    return ptComments.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
"CommentCell", for: indexPath) as? CommentCell {
        cell.configureCell(comment: ptComments[indexPath.row], 
delegate: self)
        return cell
    }

    return UITableViewCell()
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share the commtsVC?

Comment: Also which array do you want to pass? the ptDatas or the ptComments?

Comment: @NickStefanidis i'm trying to pass ptData. i added the code for the CommetsVC. thank you

Comment: Can you tell me exactly the order because its a little messy.With your code you are trying to pass ptComments array and this array is empty if I am correct.

Comment: sorry for the mess, i'm still in a learning process. I'm trying to pass ptData from PatDataCell to the CommentsVC because i need to add a sub-collection in Firebase for comments. hope this makes sense. here is a screenshot https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DGYu2pfRJLjbiTGqtVB-MmP2oRm3SXna?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

In your source code `ptcomments` property in `Custom Cell` not set anywhere, it is empty in cell.

Please set correct value for `ptcomments`

UPDATE:
You try add line like `self.comments = ptdata.commentsList` to function `configurePatDataCell`

Comment: hi, if i'm understanding this correctly, i should change var ptcomments = [Comment]() with var ptcomments = [PTData]() ?   PTData has the array i need to send to another VC. thank you

Comment: @Eddie Maybe you should get list `ptcomments` from data source of you(maybe is `ptdata`). Current, You only declare and no set value for `ptcomments`

Comment: correct ptdata is the data source, how can i send the data when i tap the UIButton? where do i declare it? how do i set the value? i apologize if i'm been dense, i'm still learning.

Comment: @Eddie What is kind of data you want to pass?. `PTData` or `[Comment]`. Where can you get list `[Comment]`?

Comment: Trying to pass the info in PTData.

Comment: @Eddie Please edit delegate method to `func patCommentBtnTapped (ptData: PTData)` and edit `patCommentBtnTapped` method,  and property in `CommentsVC`